# Factory error while trying to build DataStore with GeoTools

Tags: wfs, geotools, ogc

I am creating a simple java program that will handle the response of my WFS OGC server and display the image behind a given link.

The link I use for generating an image:

http://localhost:8180/gss/native?service=map&method=map&ace_name=XXX&centre=XXX,XXX

The link given is an image layer in the returned xml and looks like this:

http://localhost:8180/gss/resource/map/mapXXX.jpeg?token=-XXX

I used a tutorial that seemed handy and it is from 25-SNAPSHOT, the same version I use:
https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs-ng.html

The example class at the bottom of the page makes use of the DataStoreFinder which I found is deprecated. So the "new" thing is supposed to be the WFSDataStoreFactory and the WFSDataStore, but the error also occurs on these lines:

```
WFSDataStoreFactory factory = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
try{
    WFSDataStore dataStore = factory.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/factory/Factory

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>WFSProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WFSProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>25-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-cql</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wfs</artifactId>
            <version>16.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wfs-ng</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>refdataset-1.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Java class:

```
package org.geotools.WFSProject;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.geotools.data.*;
import org.geotools.data.DataAccessFactory.Param;
import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.FeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.Query;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore;
//import org.geotools.data.AbstractDataStoreFactory;
//import org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.AbstractDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.parameter.FloatParameter;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.impl.WFSDataAccessFactory;

import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.metadata.iso.extent.GeographicBoundingBoxImpl;
import org.geotools.parameter.DefaultParameterDescriptor;
import org.geotools.parameter.DefaultParameterDescriptorGroup;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
import org.geotools.util.factory.GeoTools;
import org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler;
import org.opengis.feature.Feature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;
import org.opengis.filter.spatial.Intersects;
import org.opengis.geometry.BoundingBox;
import org.opengis.geometry.Envelope;
import org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.GeometryFactory;
import org.opengis.metadata.extent.GeographicBoundingBox;
import org.opengis.parameter.ParameterDescriptorGroup;
import org.opengis.parameter.ParameterValue;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.util.factory.Factory;
import org.geotools.util.factory.*;
import org.geotools.factory.*;
import org.geotools.util.factory.AbstractFactory;

import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.geometry.GeneralEnvelope;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;

public class WFSConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newTry();
    }



    public static void newTry() {
        String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8180/gssogc/ogc?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities";
        Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
        // connectionParameters.put("url", getCapabilities );
        connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities);
        // connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:MAXFEATURES", 50);
        WFSDataStoreFactory factory = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
        try {
            WFSDataStore dataStore = factory.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
            SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("Name");
            SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures();
            while(fc.features().hasNext()){
                SimpleFeature sf = fc.features().next();
                System.out.println(sf);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        
        // Feature type: FeatureTypeList in getcapabilities
        /*
        String typeNames[] = data.getTypeNames();
        String typeName = typeNames[0];
        SimpleFeatureType schema = data.getSchema(typeName);

        // Step 4 - target
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = data.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        System.out.println("Metadata Bounds:" + source.getBounds());
        */
    }}
```

I found a couple issues that looked like mine, but no solutions have worked for me yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to mix a (very) old module in with modern ones:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wfs</artifactId>
        <version>16.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

will not work with 25-SNAPSHOT. You need to import `gt-wfs-ng` which replaced `gt-wfs` some time ago.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wfs-ng</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm also not sure where you got the idea that `DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(...)` is deprecated, it's still the recommended way of finding a datastore as far as I know.

And, finally, your while loop should only fetch one iterator and make sure to close it:

```
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures(query);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = fc.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature sf = itr.next();
        System.out.println(sf);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was indeed the mixing of old and new. I looked at this before and tinkered with it but I was not aware I only needed the one. I will test out the other pointers, thank you so much!